# Div: Height 100% of enclosing div

Tags: css

I am trying to make the sidebar expand to fit the height of the container. What am I missing?
    
    
    
    
    ​

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.sidebar {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}

.column {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}​
```

Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewtomici/8vPYc/)

Comment: @MihaiIorga It seems that the OP wants the container to be as hight as the `.column` element...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes, I know, but how you can get 100% from a container with no height ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga I want the column to hold data that could make the container bigger than the min-height. So I want the sidebar to keep the size of the container.

Comment: @MihaiIorga The container *does* have a height (obviously). It's just that its height is not explicitly set, but computed from its contents..

Comment: @ŠimeVidas it is computed on display, but on browser render that is null.

Comment: @MihaiIorga The height of the container can be retrieved via its `.offsetHeight` property. This value will *not* be null. Also, `getComputedHeight( elem ).height` will also not be null.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas on display, not on render, what he wants it is impossible with just css.

Comment: @MihaiIorga Render and display are synonyms in this context, aren't they? The browser renders/paints/displays the page. I'm not sure what you mean by "render". Also, `.offsetHeight` works (i.e. returns the height) even if the element is not displayed.

Comment: I believe render = when browser starts to "paint" one element at a time, display = when is fully rendered

Comment: @MihaiIorga So, you're saying that `.offsetHeight` doesn't return the correct value during the render phase? Only once the page is displayed can we start using this property?

Comment: @MihaiIorga I guess sachleen's answer is the perfect choice. Thank you (Multumesc :))

Comment: Yes, I know, I've just answered your question :) what you where missing :)

Answer (score 3):

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.sidebar {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.column {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}​
```

Make the container position relative so you can absolutely position the sidebar inside of it. Then set the top and bottom positions of the sidebar to 0 so it stretches the full height. You also have to push the column div out from the left by the width of the sidebar.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vPYc/3/)

Comment: what if the `column` makes the `container` bigger?

Comment: What if the OP wants the container's height to be dependent on the other child (the `.column` element)?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas exactly, that's what I want